# Spark Performance issue - Writing partitions to S3 as individual files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I'm running a spark job whose job is to scan a large file and split it into smaller files. The file is in Json Lines format and I'm trying to partition it by a certain column (*id*) and save each partition as a separate file to S3. The file size is about 12 GB but there are about 500000 distinct values of *id*. The query is taking almost 15 hours. What can I do to improve performance? Is Spark a poor choice for such a task? Please note that I do have the liberty to making sure that the source as a fixed number of  rows per *id*.

```
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.transforms import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, substring, instr, locate
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
# Get parameters that were passed to the job
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['INPUT_FOLDER', 'OUTPUT_FOLDER', 'ID_TYPE', 'DATASET_DATE'])

id_type = args["ID_TYPE"]
output_folder = "{}/{}/{}".format(args["OUTPUT_FOLDER"], id_type, args["DATASET_DATE"])
input_folder = "{}/{}/{}".format(args["INPUT_FOLDER"], id_type, args["DATASET_DATE"])


INS_SCHEMA = StructType([
    StructField("camera_capture_timestamp", StringType(), True),
    StructField(id_type, StringType(), True),
    StructField("image_uri", StringType(), True)
])


data = spark.read.format("json").load(input_folder, schema=INS_SCHEMA)

data = data.withColumn("fnsku_1", F.col("fnsku"))

data.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy(["fnsku_1"]).mode('append').json(output_folder)
```

I have tried repartition instead of coalesce too.

*I'm using AWS Glue*

Comment: why do you need `coalesce(1)`? Any reason? - Ah... mode append, I see.

Comment: Spark uses the distributed file system and so the single file process is really bad and it makes job slow down.

Comment: So are you stating that if I have multiple files as source it will be faster? I thought Spark will use distributed processing even if the source is a single file.

Comment: I mean when you write, not reading.

Comment: I'm writing to multiple files. Just that I need one file per partition.

Comment: So what happened when you tried `repartition("fnsku_1")` instead of `coalesce(1)`? The difference between the two is that `repartition` creates a stage boundary whereas `coalesce` can be "optimized" forward (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce _...However if you're doing a drastic coalesce..._)

Comment: Could you please update Spark UI and ganglia chart  in question and plz mention how you are runing EMR or Glue ?

Comment: @lalatnayak Have you tried reading this via Glue dynamic frame ? Also how many columns does your source data have ? It will be good to update your question with sample records.And is there any reason why you are using coalesce(1) with 1 as value instead of repartition(totalfilesize/n not less than (128 MB) ) ?

Answer (score 4):

Please consider the following as one of possible options. It would be awesome to see if it helped :)

First, if you coalesce, as said @Lamanus in the comments, it means that you will reduce the number of partitions, hence also reduce the number of
writer task, hence shuffle all data to 1 task. It can be the first factor to improve.

To overcome the issue, ie. write a file per partition and keep the parallelization level, you can change the logic on the following one:

```scala
object TestSoAnswer extends App {

  private val testSparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Demo groupBy and partitionBy").master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
  import testSparkSession.implicits._

  // Input dataset with 5 partitions
  val dataset = testSparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    TestData("a", 0), TestData("a", 1), TestData("b", 0), TestData("b", 1),
    TestData("c", 1), TestData("c", 2)
  ), 5).toDF("letter", "number")

  dataset.as[TestData].groupByKey(row => row.letter)
    .flatMapGroups {
      case (_, values) => values
    }.write.partitionBy("letter").mode("append").json("/tmp/test-parallel-write")

}

case class TestData(letter: String, number: Int)
```

## How does it work?

First, the code performs a shuffle to collect all rows related to a specific key (**same as for the partitioning**) to the same
partitions. So that, it will perform the write on all the rows belonging to the key at once. Some time ago I wrote [a blog
post about `partitionBy` method](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/apache-spark-sql-partitionby-shuffle-not-shuffle/read). Roughly, internally it will sort the records on the given partition and later write them
one-by-one into the file.

That way we get the plan like this one, where only 1 shuffle, so processing-consuming operation is present:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, TestData, true])).letter, true, false) AS letter#22, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, TestData, true])).number AS number#23]
+- MapGroups TestSoAnswer$$$Lambda$1236/295519299@55c50f52, value#18.toString, newInstance(class TestData), [value#18], [letter#3, number#4], obj#21: TestData
   +- *(1) Sort [value#18 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(value#18, 200), true, [id=#15]
         +- AppendColumnsWithObject TestSoAnswer$$$Lambda$1234/1747367695@6df11e91, [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, TestData, true])).letter, true, false) AS letter#3, knownnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, TestData, true])).number AS number#4], [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#18]
            +- Scan[obj#2]
```

The output of the `TestSoAnswer` executed twice looks like that:

```
test-parallel-write % ls
_SUCCESS letter=a letter=b letter=c
test-parallel-write % ls letter=a
part-00170-68245d8b-b155-40ca-9b5c-d9fb746ac76c.c000.json part-00170-cd90d64f-43c6-4582-aae6-fe443b6617f4.c000.json

test-parallel-write % ls letter=b
part-00161-68245d8b-b155-40ca-9b5c-d9fb746ac76c.c000.json part-00161-cd90d64f-43c6-4582-aae6-fe443b6617f4.c000.json

test-parallel-write % ls letter=c
part-00122-68245d8b-b155-40ca-9b5c-d9fb746ac76c.c000.json part-00122-cd90d64f-43c6-4582-aae6-fe443b6617f4.c000.json
```

You can also control the [number of records written per file with this configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689677/how-to-control-output-files-size-in-spark-structured-streaming).

Edit: Didn't see the comment of @mazaneicha but indeed, you can try with `repartition("partitioning column")`! It's even more clear than the grouping expression.

Best,

Bartosz.

Comment: Thanks. One of my team mates is going to try this and respond in the comments section

Comment: So with this approach the run time shortened from 50 hours to 20 hours! Quite an improvement but I need to bring it down to under 5 hours. I was processing a 50 GB file and the partition column has 1.7 million distinct values. Is there any thing else you suggest at this point?

Comment: What is the format of the file? Compressed vs not compressed?  
If you want to give a try meantime, maybe you can split the big job into smaller ones and by splitting I mean that each job filters on different partition column range. You run these jobs in parallel and unless you have some contention on the reading, it should accelerate the time. I don't see the logs but suppose then that for 1.7mln partitions, the I/O part for writing takes time and with a single process, don't see a way to accelerate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use Spark for anything other than to split the file into smaller versions of itself, then I would say Spark is a poor choice. You'd be better off doing this within AWS following an approach such as the one given in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139995/split-s3-file-into-smaller-files-of-1000-lines)

Assuming you have an EC2 instance available, you'd run something like this:

```
aws s3 cp s3://input_folder/12GB.json - | split -l 1000 - output.
aws s3 cp output.* s3://output_folder/
```

If you're looking to do some further processing of the data in Spark, you're going to want to repartition the data to chunks between 128MB and [1 GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918663/is-it-better-to-have-one-large-parquet-file-or-lots-of-smaller-parquet-files#:%7E:text=Aim%20for%20around%201GB%20per,that%20needs%20to%20be%20considered.). With the default (snappy) compression, you typically end up with 20% of the original file size. So, in your case: between (12/5) ~3 and (12/5/8) ~20 partitions, so:

```
data = spark.read.format("json").load(input_folder, schema=INS_SCHEMA) 

dataPart = data.repartition(12)
```

This is not actually a particularly large data set for Spark and should not be as cumbersome to deal with.

Saving as parquet gives you a good recovery point, and re-reading the data will be very fast. The total file size will be about 2.5 GB.

Comment: This will work only if there are an equal number of rows per partition column.

Comment: data.repartition(12) will reshuffle the data in the RDD randomly to fit 12 partitions. No partition column given, none used. Ref: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html